# `then` on Kleisli's of Different Input Types?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task

case class AppConfig(x: Int, y: String)

val x = Kleisli[Task, Int, Boolean] { 
   case i: Int => if (i === 42) Task.now(true) else Task.now(false)
}

val y = Kleisli[Task, String, Unit] { 
    case s: String => Task.delay { println(s"$s was here") } 
}
```

I cannot call `x >> y` due to failed compilation:

```
scala> x >> y
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.Kleisli[scalaz.concurrent.Task,String,Unit]
 required: scalaz.Kleisli[scalaz.concurrent.Task,Int,?]
       x >> y
            ^
```

As a result, is it reasonable to change `x` and `y`'s types from `Kleisli[Task, Int, Boolean]` and `Kleisli[Task, String, Boolean]` to `Kleisli[Task, AppConfig, Boolean]`?

If not, please suggest a better alternative and your rationale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
x *** y
```

which will give you `Kleisli[Task, (Int, String), (Boolean, Unit)]`.

The `***` comes from the `Arrow` syntax, and means parallel composition (as opposed to sequential composition of `>>=` or `>>`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happening: since in Scalaz `Kleisli[M, A, B]` can be interpreted as Scala function `A => M[B]`, there's built-in reader monad instance for it, which is used in this case. Reader monad is defined over functions `R => M[A]` reading from fixed type `R`. So you need input types of `Kleisli` arrows to match in order to use it, which is not the case. Kleisli composition, `>=>`, is also unavailable: it requires result type of the first `Kleisli` (`B` in signature) to match input type `A` of the second. You can supply arguments and move down to the `Task` level:

```
x(42) >> y("abc")
```

Alternatively, if you want to stay at `Kleisli` level, you may want to use parallel arrow composition, as stated in other answer:

```
import scalaz.syntax.arrow._ // if you're not importing whole Scalaz
import Function.const
(x *** y).map(const()) // use map to ignore result
```

Note that it also means you'll need to supply your arguments later eventually.